# Separate Icons for Open Applications and Favourites in Ubuntu Dock

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Is it possible somehow to separate the icons for favourite apps and open apps?

Right now I have them all in the vertical taskbar to the left (Ubuntu Dock), so it happens very often that I want to switch app and instead click on a closed app, and it's a huge hassle to wait for it to open and close.

I don't want to get rid of favourites completely, but it would be nice if there was a setup to keep them in separate places on the screen, or maybe let the open apps icons float to the top of the bar, so that they are not so easily misclicked.

Answer (score 0):

So your issue appears to be that sometimes you click the wrong icon on the dash, i.e., not the icon of the app you want to switch to, but another icon next to it, of a favorite that is not running.

Unfortunately, this is not supported with the default dock. There, the idea is one of "launch or switch to", i.e., clicking an icon either switches to the application if it is running, or launches the application. Favorite icons remain in their fixed place.

You could change your workflow somewhat by not including any favorites on the dock. Then, you could launch from the "Show applications" overview. The "Frequent" tab will show all your frequently applications anyway. Switching then is on the Dock, which at that point will only contain icons of running programs. Small drawback is that launching is then two clicks away instead than one.

Alternatively, you could use the Gnome shell extension "Dash to Panel". Going into the extension's options, you can configure that launchers and running applications are separated. The drawback here (or the advantage according to your taste) is that this extension will quite significantly change the look and feel of your desktop: it will change the current topbar and icons to a single bar at the bottom of the screen, much like in Windows 10.

Of course, you could entirely move to a desktop that supports this workflow from the start, such as Cinnamon, xfce or Mate.